# Jersey and AOP without Spring

Tags: java, logging, jersey, aop

I am using Grizzly with Jersey 2.1.
I would like to add an aspect for logging purpose (before and after each method execution).
Is it possibile to do this without using Spring or Google-Guice?

Thanks

Comment: You could use AspectJ, but that might be more complicated than integrating with Spring or Guice, since it is a language of its own.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something very similar by using [monitoring](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring.html) features offered by Jersey (particularly via [event listeners](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring.html#d0e10475)). Basically you need to create and register an instance of [ApplicationEventListener](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEventListener.html) and [RequestEventListener](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEventListener.html) where you would be listening to [RESOURCE_METHOD_START](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEvent.Type.html#RESOURCE_METHOD_START) and [RESOURCE_METHOD_FINISHED](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEvent.Type.html#RESOURCE_METHOD_FINISHED) events.

```
@Provider
public class MyApplicationEventListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        return new RequestEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(final RequestEvent event) {
                switch (event.getType()) {
                    case RESOURCE_METHOD_START:
                        logMethod(event.getUriInfo(), true);
                        break;

                    case RESOURCE_METHOD_FINISHED:
                        logMethod(event.getUriInfo(), false);
                        break;
                }
            }

            private void logMethod(final ExtendedUriInfo uriInfo, final boolean entering) {
                final Class<?> resource = uriInfo
                        .getMatchedResources().get(0).getClass();

                final Method method = uriInfo
                        .getMatchedResourceMethod()
                        .getInvocable()
                        .getHandlingMethod();

                if (entering) {
                    logger.entering(resource.toString(), method.toString());
                } else {
                    logger.exiting(resource.toString(), method.toString());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Register the listener into your application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // Add root resources.
        classes.add(HelloWorldResource.class);
        
        // Add ApplicationEventListener.
        classes.add(MyApplicationEventListener.class);
        
        return classes;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** These events are fired only around a resource method "to-be-executed" and not for sub-resource locators that might be executed during resource matching phase.

---

#### EDIT 1

To log each invoked method (even methods invoked from a JAX-RS resource method) refer to the [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) project.

Comment: Ok, it works but how can I obtain the same results for method called by the resource? I would like to log input/output parameters also of the methods called by the resource method.

Comment: For this you're gonna need to use AspectJ or similar library (see `EDIT 1`).